# How to accurately parse smtp message status code (DSN)?

Tags: email, email-bounces

RFC1893 claims that status codes will come in the format below you can read more [here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1893.html).

But our bounce management system is having a hard time parsing error status code from bounce messages.  We are able to get the raw message, but depending on the email server the code will come in different places.  Is there any rule on how to parse this type of messages to obtain better results.  We are not looking for the 100% solution but at least 80%.

> This document defines a new set of status codes to report mail system
>      conditions.  These status codes are intended to be used for media and
>      language independent status reporting.  They are not intended for
>      system specific diagnostics.
>
> The syntax of the new status codes
>   is defined as:
>
> ```
>       status-code = class "." subject "." detail
>       class = "2"/"4"/"5"
>       subject = 1*3digit
>       detail = 1*3digit
> ```
>
> White-space characters and comments
>   are NOT allowed within a status-
>   code.  Each numeric sub-code within
>   the status-code MUST be expressed
>   without leading zero digits.

The quote above from the RFC tells one thing but then the text below from a leading tool on bounce management says something different, where I can get a good source of standard status codes:

> Return Code   Description
>   0 UNDETERMINED - (ie. Recipient Reply)
>   10    HARD BOUNCE - (ie. User Unknown)
>   20    SOFT BOUNCE - General
>   21    SOFT BOUNCE - Dns Failure
>   22    SOFT BOUNCE - Mailbox Full
>   23    SOFT BOUNCE - Message Too Large
>   30    BOUNCE - NO EMAIL ADDRESS. VERY RARE!
>   40    GENERAL BOUNCE
>   50    MAIL BLOCK - General
>   51    MAIL BLOCK - Known Spammer
>   52    MAIL BLOCK - Spam Detected
>   53    MAIL BLOCK - Attachment Detected
>   54    MAIL BLOCK - Relay Denied
>   60    AUTO REPLY - (ie. Out Of Office)
>   70    TRANSIENT BOUNCE
>   80    SUBSCRIBE Request
>   90    UNSUBSCRIBE/REMOVE Request
>   100   CHALLENGE-RESPONSE

Comment: The status code from the "leading tool" is their own proprietary codes for their "newsletter" management system. DSN says nothing about Subscriptions or Spam. Have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3463

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it's a full answer, but [this algorithm for detecting bounces](http://lamsonproject.org/blog/2009-07-09.html) might be useful.

Comment: This is very helpful Steven.  Have you used this project for any of your development projects?

Comment: Can't say I have, but it did look like it was solving the same problem you're dealing with.  I don't know your development environment, so I likewise couldn't say whether you should consider using that project as-is or adapting the regexp algorithm to your needs.  But any working example has to be better than dry RFC's.

Comment: Your link is dead.